# ASP.NET where does throw new exception error get displayed

Tags: asp.net, exception

Code snippet..

```
if (regionalApprover == null)
{
   throw new Exception(string.Format("The regional approver for {0} could not be found", companyData["Country"]));
}
```

How does the user actually see this error ?

Comment: Do it. Try it. Is there an error display? Besides, where is this code? In a WebForms page code-behind? In an MVC controller action? In some business-layer code? When you tried it, what happened? Was there no error display at all? In that case, it's probably a case of prematurely swallowed exceptions by `try{}catch{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of an unhandled exception depends on a variety of factors, including

- where the web request is coming from,
- the settings of the [`<customErrors> Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) in your web.config and
- the contents of [`Application_Error` in your `global.asax` codebehind file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx).

In the default configuration, IIS will log the error into the Windows event log. In addition, it is shown in the browser by ASP.NET if the web request comes from localhost.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to display an error message on the page (that the user is supposed to see), don't use Exceptions.

It's a much better idea to add an errors section to the page that you can add the messages to before showing the page to the user.